# What will happen when using `defer` in chained method call?

Tags: go

for example,

```golang
defer profile.Start().Stop()
```

is that equal to:

```golang
p := profile.Start()
defer p.Stop()
```

Comment: The two are equivalent, because what you're deferring is the call to `Stop`, and parameters (including the method's receiver, i.e. `profile.Start()` here) of a deferred method call are evaluated at the `defer` statement, not when the method call eventually executes.

Comment: excellent explain! thanks a lot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can `defer` a long chain of method calls but only the last function call will be deferred and all other calls will be evaluated immediately with the `defer` statement.

```golang
func foo() {
   defer A().B().C().D().E().F().G().H()
   // Only call to H() is deferred and all other function calls must be 
   // evaluated immediately to reach H.
}
```

For more info see [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#defer).

Answer (score 2):

The defer in the cascaded function defer only to the last function call. The other functions will be called immediately as per the order of evaluation.

For example

```
func secondInteration(p *profile){
    fmt.Println("~~~~~~~~~~ Second Iteration ~~~~~~~~")
    defer p.start().stop()
    p.intermediate()
    
}
```

This will only defer the stop function. Start and intermediate will be evaluated as a normal execution.

The above snippet will print

```
~~~~~~~~~~ Second Iteration ~~~~~~~~
start
Intermediate
stop
```

Whereas if you have more than one deferred function, the functions will be pushed into the Stack and the last pushed defer function will be evaluated first

For example

```
func thirdInteration(p *profile){
    fmt.Println("~~~~~~~~~~ Third Iteration ~~~~~~~~")
    defer p.start()
    defer p.intermediate()
    defer p.stop()
}
```

This outputs into

```
~~~~~~~~~~ Third Iteration ~~~~~~~~
stop
Intermediate
start
```

So effectively the above code snippets are the same in this context as only one method is chained and we have one line of code.

We can find more information [here](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) on Go Blog.

The above code snippets can be found [here](https://play.golang.org/p/alxf8ZrEtEl)